# What is dipolar charge distribution?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, dirac-delta-distributions, dipole, point-particles

An electric dipole is a system of two opposite point charges when their separation goes to zero and their charge goes to infinity in a way that the product of the charge and the separation remains finite.

1. How can we have a continuous volume charge distribution from such a collection of point charges?
2. In [the article 'Electric dipole' at Knowino](https://m.tau.ac.il/~tsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Electric_dipole.html)
   it is said that

   > The charge distribution is written in terms of Dirac delta functions:
   >    $$\rho (\mathbf{r})=q_1 \delta (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_1)+q_2 \delta (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_2)$$

Here $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ are the position vectors of $q_1$ and $q_2$ and $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}_1-\mathbf{r}_2$. Please explain why do we need Dirac delta in describing dipolar charge distribution?

Comment: The 3D Dirac delta function describes the charge density of a point charge. There is nothing continuous about it.

Comment: Two point charges have a dipole moment but are not technically a dipole. A true dipole is when their separation goes to zero and their charge goes to infinity in a way that the product of the charge and the separation remains finite.

Comment: Do you mean that dipole charge distribution is not a continuous distribution?

Comment: Dirac $\delta$ functions are a type of distribution function ([generalized function](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function)); cf. [Ibragimov 2010](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6446) ch. 8.

Comment: Note that you're misinterpreting the role of $\mathbf r$ in that formula - it represents the point at which the charge density $\rho(\mathbf r)$ is being evaluated, and not any intrinsic quantity of the charge density itself.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* Dirac delta functions to describe a dipolar charge distribution. There's a very wide range of charge distributions whose electric fields are exactly dipolar ([this Q&A describes one such example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336512/is-there-a-finite-sized-charge-distribution-whose-electric-field-is-exactly-th)) and an even wider class whose electric fields are dominated by a dipolar asymptotic when you're away from the support of the charge distribution (basically: every neutral charge distribution with a nonzero dipole moment).

The expression you've asked about is simply the correct encapsulation into a single analytical formula for the charge density $\rho(\mathbf r)$ that corresponds to two point charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ at positions $\mathbf r_1$ and $\mathbf r_2$. This needs to be fairly singular (in technical language, it's a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), not a function) because point charges are not strictly describable as (continuous) volumetric charge densities.